# jsTree : refresh content after an AJAX call then open all

Tags: jquery, jstree

I have loaded a jsTree with an AJAX call that returns JSON data. Another AJAX call is made when a node is moved and I want the tree to be refreshed:

```
$("#my_tree").jstree({
   "core": {
      ...
})
.on("move_node.jstree", function(node,nodes){
   $.ajax({
      url: "/path/to/ajax",
      type: "POST",
      data: {
         action: "move",
         ...
      },
      success: function () {
         $('#my_div').jstree(true).refresh(false, true);
      }
   });
})
```

That works, but I'd like the tree to be open on refresh. This doesn't work, the tree remains collapsed.

```
      success: function () {
        $('#my_tree').jstree(true).refresh(false, true);
        $('#my_tree').jstree("open_all");
        [or even $("#my_tree").trigger("loaded.jstree"); ]
      }
```

However, 'open_all' works fine when the page is loaded with:

```
.bind("loaded.jstree", function (event, data) {
   $(this).jstree("open_all");
});
```

How can I refresh and open the tree? Thanks for your help.

[Edit] Precision after Tomalak's answer:

After the move is done, some processes occur on the database side and the new content must be loaded via AJAX then displayed. That's the reason why the tree is refreshed.

Comment: Initially, the tree is loaded on the client side. You move a node. That means, the client side is then already in the intended state (node sits at new position). You tell the server of the move via Ajax. The Ajax call succeeds (the server has saved the move). **Result** You don't need to refresh the tree at all - it already is exactly as it should be. (But when the Ajax call fails, you need to move back the node & inform the user of the error.)

Comment: @Tomalak if I were not to do it I would not ask how to do it... ;-) After the move is done, some processes occur on the database side and the new content must be loaded via AJAX then displayed. One more time, it works fine, I just want to get the tree opened after a refresh.

Comment: But you already do... at least the first part. On Ajax success, do nothing.

Comment: A thread about the "On Ajax error" part is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9121564/how-to-rollback-nodes-that-couldnt-be-moved-in-jstree

Comment: My point is, you don't have to restore the tree state (what is parts are open, selected, or whatever else) when you don't destroy the tree state. Refreshing the tree destroys the tree state. If you can avoid that, you're better off.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this reopens the tree after a refresh:

```
.bind("refresh.jstree", function (event, data) {
  $(this).jstree("open_all");
}
```